# Windows firewall always prompts when starting Go web server

Tags: go, webserver

Every time i start go web sever windows firewall prompts to allow access, how can i allow everytime through firewall when it's go web server

Answer (score 4):

I just came up with a solution. I created an inbound rule that always allow connection at a port my go program runs on

Answer (score 0):

This is a firewall problem and has not really anything to do with go. Also please specify the windows version you're using

Comment: First tnxs...yeah it's windows firewall problem and not specific to go but in go when it build the project it's output executable is always named differently..and windows assumes this is a new program and not prompted before

Comment: Which version of windows is it? 7,8,10?

Comment: and how do you compile your go program? The name of the executable should be always the same

Comment: The latest one...win 10...1909.
I use 'go run file.go' cmd command

Comment: yeah...i could go 'build input.go output.exe'
'Output.exe'
But that 2 step process and not suited when in development

Comment: are you using the linux subsystem? Because there you can chain commands with &&. Not sure how it is for windows

Comment: I've been having the same issue on a mac. It is relevant to Go because it only happens w/ my Go build. I've tried reflex/gin and both have this issue whereas nodemon never required such actions.